# Перенос элементов flexbox на другую строку

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Есть flex-контейнер, в котором содержатся 4 элемента:

```css
.catalog__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.catalog__items__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog__items">
  <div class="catalog__items__item">1товар</div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item">2товар</div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item">3товар</div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item">4товар</div>
</div>
```

Они расположены в одном ряду, `flew-wrap` их переносит, если экран сужается, сначала таким образом, что идут 3 в ряд, а 1 переносится на 2 строку, а затем уже так, как надо, т.е. по 2 в ряд.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как сделать, чтобы убрать это состояние, где переносится лишь 1 элемент.
Т.е. чтобы сначала были по 4 в ряд, а затем по 2 в ряд.

Кто знает, как это сделать? Уже 5 страниц гугла перелистал, везде про `flex-wrap` написано, но он не дает нужного результата

Comment: Сгруппировать итемы по 2 в контейнере?

Comment: @Moonvvell верно, но как это сделать? Оболочку для каждых двух элементов?

Comment: Ну это первое что приходит в голову. По 2 итема в собственный див.

Comment: Уже сделал, написал ответ :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Flexbox item — перенос на новую строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690500/flexbox-item-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov дубликат вопроса? Как может быть дубликатом вопрос, который был задан раньше?

Comment: @Alexxosipov https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3312/220571

Comment: @Alexxosipov Отозвал голос за закрытие, так как данный вопрос имеет свою специфику.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.catalog__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.catalog__items__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.catalog__items::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  order: 0;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.catalog__items__item:nth-child(n + 3) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog__items">
  <div class="catalog__items__item">1товар</div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item">2товар</div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item">3товар</div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item">4товар</div>
</div>
```

Comment: border: solid 1px black; - это только для наглядности.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

Добавил в нужном месте с помощью медиа-запроса марджины по бокам, чтобы у контейнера не было места для 3 элементов в ряд.

Answer (score 0):

Можно избежать использования в данном случае медиазапросов. Раз вы знаете, что надо переносить по два элемента, то положите их в отдельные блоки по две штуки.

В данном случае:

```css
.catalog__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* дополнительный контейнер без flex-wrap: wrap */
.catalog__items__item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

/* демонстрируем маленькую ширину экрана */
.catalog__items--reduced {
  width: 100px;
}

/* исходные стили, которые для данной демонстрации вообще нерелевантны */
.catalog__items__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<h2>Обычный экран</h2>

<div class="catalog__items">
  <div class="catalog__items__item-wrapper">
    <div class="catalog__items__item">1товар</div>
    <div class="catalog__items__item">2товар</div>
  </div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item-wrapper">
    <div class="catalog__items__item">3товар</div>
    <div class="catalog__items__item">4товар</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Маленький экран</h2>

<div class="catalog__items catalog__items--reduced">
  <div class="catalog__items__item-wrapper">
    <div class="catalog__items__item">1товар</div>
    <div class="catalog__items__item">2товар</div>
  </div>
  <div class="catalog__items__item-wrapper">
    <div class="catalog__items__item">3товар</div>
    <div class="catalog__items__item">4товар</div>
  </div>
</div>
```