# Flexbox item — перенос на новую строку

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Есть Flexbox сетка.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
</div>
```

Как перенести `.new-string` на новую строку вместе с элементами, которые идут после него?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29732575/1548895

Comment: Ну line же, а не sting...

Comment: @Qwertiy, вспомнил первый перевод слова "строка" :) Не хочешь предложить свой вариант? Вряд ли это единственные решения. Кто-то должен был придумать лучше

Comment: @Yuri, вариант с margin'ом можно допилить. А так, без изменения разметки ничего не придумывается.

Comment: Разумнее было бы использовать display: grid; , нежели так извращаться костылями ниже..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>Перевод [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733127/1548895).</sub>

Примечание переводчика: flex-элемент (flex item) — непосредственный ребёнок блока с `display: flex`.

---

Наиболее простое и надёжное решение — это вставка flex-элементов в правильных местах. Если они достаточно широкие (`width: 100%`), они будут создавать перенос строки.

```css
.container {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px
}
.item:nth-child(4n - 1) {
  background: silver;
}
.line-break {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Но это уродливо и не семантически. Вместо этого, мы можем генерировать псевдоэлементы внутры flex-контейнера и использовать свойство `order` чтобы перемещать их в нужные места.

```css
.container {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px
}
.item:nth-child(3n) {
  background: silver;
}
.container::before, .container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
}
.item:nth-child(n + 4) {
  order: 1;
}
.item:nth-child(n + 7) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Но есть ограничение: flex-контейнер может иметь только псевдоэлементы `::before` и `::after`. Это значит, что мы можем создать только 2 переноса строки.

Чтобы разрешить это, вы можете генерировать псевдоэлементы внутри flex-элементов  вместо flex-контейнера. Таким способом вы не будете ограничены двумя. Но эти псевдоэлементы не будут flex-элементами, поэтому не будут создавать переносы строк.

Но, к счастью, спецификация [CSS Display L3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) ввела [`display: contents`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-outside-contents) (в данный момент поддерживаемая только Firefox 37):

> Элемент сам по себе не генерирует никаких блоков, но его дети и
>   псевдоэлементы генерируют блоки как обычно. С целью генерации блоков
>   и разметки элемент будет расцениваться как будто он был заменён его
>   детьми и псевдоэлементами в дереве документа.

Поэтому вы можете применять `display: contents` к детям flex-контейнера и обернуть содержимое каждого внутрь дополнительного блок. Таким образом flex-элементы будут этими дополнительными обёртками и псевдоэлементами детей.

```css
.container {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  display: contents;
}
.item > div {
  width: 100px;
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.item:nth-child(3n) > div {
  background: silver;
}
.item:nth-child(3n)::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><div>1</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>2</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>3</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>4</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>5</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>6</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>7</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>8</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>9</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div>10</div></div>
</div>
```

Кроме того, в соответствии с [Fragmenting Flex Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#pagination) и [CSS Fragmentation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-break-3/), flexbox позволяет принудительные переносы с помощью [`break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before), [`break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after) или их псевдонимов в CSS 2.1:

```css
.item:nth-child(3n) {
  page-break-after: always; /* Синтаксис CSS 2.1 */
  break-after: always; /* Новый синтаксис */
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px
}
.item:nth-child(3n) {
  page-break-after: always;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Принудительные переносы строк во flexbox ещё широко не поддерживаются, но они работают в Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Во `flexbox`, к сожалению, не силен, но вот такой трюк помню:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  
}

.flex:after {
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  order:0;
}

.item.new-string,
.item.new-string ~ .item {
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если потом ещё одну строку понадобится создать? :)

Comment: @Yuri а вот тут уже проблемка, да :)

Comment: Там был ещё какой-то нюанс, но я его забыл :(

Comment: Прости, что забрал верный ответ. Но появился ответ лучше

Answer (score 5):

Решил с помощью добавления элемента разрыва

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.new-string {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="new-string"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Qwertiy, жаль, что flex не всё-всё может решить :) Тогда бы все верстальщики почувствовали себя в Раю

Answer (score 3):

Может, как-нить с марджином попробовать поиграться?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: calc(100% - 125px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: С таким подходом flexbox не нужен :(

Answer (score 3):

```
.container {
  display: flex;   
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Этого должно хватить!

Answer (score 0):

Можно в разметку вставить горизонтальную линию

```css
flex hr {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="item new-string">item new-string</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Примеры надо проверять....