# Не получается сделать отступ между блоками

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

В ряду 3 блока, нужно чтобы между ними был отступ и их размер подгонялся друг под друга. Как можно так сделать? Использую Bootstrap 4
(Картинка 1 - на данный момент)
(Картинка 2 примерный вариант)

[image: Картинка 1]

[image: Картинка 2]

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
      Запрос к БД
      Цикл while
    <div class="col-4 mb-2">
      <div class="p-3 mb-3 bg-warning rounded">
        <h4><b> Вывод из БД </b></h4>
        <p> Вывод из БД</b> <p align="left">Вывод из БД</b></i></p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: А не пробовали flexbox использовать?

Comment: @Юрий, не пробовал, сейчас попробовал через него, но выводит все в строку и не переносит на следующую строку. Не подскажите, как сделать через него, но чтобы была задумка, которую я описал

Comment: там должны быть разные зазоры? как перенос на другие строчки должен выглядеть?

Comment: @Юрий, зазоры одинаковые, между строками просто пустое место и на следующих строках снова идут эти блоки (3 штуки на каждую строку)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690500/flexbox-item-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: space-beetwen;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  /*   чтобы переносилось */
}
.item{
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(30% - 30px);  /*   отнимать необходимый вам  margin умноженный на 2 */
  margin: 15px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете boootstrap 4, то:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mb-2">
      <div class="bg-success text-white">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-2">
      <div class="bg-success text-white">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-2">
      <div class="bg-success text-white">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-2">
      <div class="bg-success text-white">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-2">
      <div class="bg-success text-white">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-2">
      <div class="bg-success text-white">
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все идет в 1 столбец, у меня просто вывод данных с БД в эти блоки и получается так 
`<main class="container mt-5">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
   // ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ И ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ ИЗ БД //
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>`

Comment: @Dаниил, добавьте код в Ваш вопрос

Comment: использовал ваше решение, заработало, но блоки не подстраиваются по ширине друг под друга. они получаются разной ширины, как можно исправить?

Comment: @Dаниил, я же пишу - добавьте Ваш код, потому как не понятно что Вы вообще хотите. В bootstrap для `.col` заданы отступы в `15px`, `.col-4` - ширина `33.333%`. ...