# Перенести последнюю ячейку на новую строку

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть таблица, в ней множество колонок. Как сделать, чтобы последняя колонка переносилась на новую строку? Пробовал сделать через флексы, но проблема в том, что для переноса нужен `flex-wrap:wrap`, а он переносит все ячейки, которые не помещаются на экране, то есть, этот вариант не подходит. Мне же нужно, чтоб переносилась исключительно последняя ячейка, а остальные могли выходить за пределы экрана сколько угодно. Возможно ли решить такое, если не через флексы, то другим способом? Условие - добавлять tr нельзя.

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.row input{
  width:100px;
}
.row td:last-of-type{
  width:100%;
}
.row textarea{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr id="row1" class="row">
    <!--Все ячейки, кроме последней, должны быть в одну строчку и могут выходить за пределы экрана-->
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><textarea>Эта ячейка должна быть на новой строчке на всю ширину</textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) своих попыток

Comment: И попробуйте посмотреть на [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/690622/7336) похожего вопроса.

Comment: @InDevX извиняюсь, добавил.

Comment: @Walstper я смотрел этот вопрос и другие, ни один не подходит.

Comment: @Sevastopol' что не так?

Comment: @InDevX добавил - ничего не дало.

Comment: @Sevastopol' в рамках одной строки - да.

Comment: @InDevX нет, мне надо, чтоб остальные ячейки не переносились. И без этого свойства результат тот же самый.

Comment: @fixer а что мешает просто в следующей tr создать 1 td?

Comment: @InDevX потому что тогда пришлось бы дорабатывать js скрипты, обрабатывающие эту таблицу, что несколько костыльно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
/* Все элементы выстраиваются в одну строку */
tr { white-space: nowrap; }

/* Все элементы блочные, обтекаются другими элементами */
td { display: inline-block; }

/* Последний элемент блочный */
td:last-child { display: block; }
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr id="row1" class="row">
    <!--Все ячейки, кроме последней, должны быть в одну строчку и могут выходить за пределы экрана-->
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td>Эта ячейка должна быть на новой строчке на всю ширину</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Воу. Оказалось так просто. Я уже думал, что это невозможно. Спасибо.